# Does curl_exec() retry if timeout?

Tags: php, curl

In my application I have to make a POST call to a webservice. They send me an XML response, basically saying "Accepted" or "Refused".
Last week I had an issue with one of these calls: I received a "Refused" response while their backend was telling me this request had been accepted.
I asked them what happened and they told me **they received 2 requests** (with the same ID - a parameter I send to them). First one was "Refused", second one was "Accepted".

I investigated: in my code, if I receive a "Refused" response, I log it, I update my database, and that's it. **I do not try again.**

The only thing would be PHP `curl` functions.
The day the problem occured, the webservice took unusual long time to response (20 seconds).
**Could `curl` have made several calls?** There is no `retry` option in the PHP function (or I didn't find it), but I'd rather ask here to be sure.

Here is my curl code.

```
$ch = curl_init();

$myArrayWithDatas = array( '...' );
$httpQueryFields = http_build_query($myArrayWithDatas);

$url = "https://www.webservice.com/api";
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $httpQueryFields);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$response = curl_exec($ch);

if (empty($response)) {
    // I log an error
    // (no trace of that in my logs)
} else {
    // I log the XML response
    // (one "Refused" response logged)
}

curl_close($ch);
```

Is there any case where this code could send 2 or more requests to the `$url`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`curl_exec` will only do 1 call.

Are you running your code via a cron job or scheduled task ? If that's the case, maybe your code has been launched twice and that would explain why there were two calls done.

Comment: It's not a cron job, I have no loop, I'll continue searching for another mistake but I wanted to be sure it can't come from curl. I'm also waiting for the webservice to tell me more. Thank you for the confirmation! :)

Comment: If I were you, I would create a unique log entry each time the webservice is called (dont use the ID you sending to identify that log entry, use some kind of UUID), I would also dump some variables such as current timestamp, `$_SERVER` (if you are executing it from command line, this will contains the args passed). This should help debug.

Comment: I log everytime I call this webservice, with all parameters sent, session and cookies, and timestamp. In my logs, I have only one call for this ID. That's why I was wondering if the issue was with curl: me logging once but curl calling several times. I'm waiting for the webservice to send me their logs, to see if it gives me a clue.

Comment: Maybe, the issue is on their side.

Comment: I just had an answer from them, indeed it was an issue on their side. But it's good to be sure curl won't cause this kind of problem. :)